# Android: Change navigation drawer email and user-name in Settings Activity

Tags: android, sqlite, android-activity, navigation, settings

For my project I have few activities, some of them have [AUTO-GENERATED navigation drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qj2lu.png), and I also have a settings activity. What I need to do is make username and email from navigation drawer changable in settings activity and save them in SQLite database, so it doesn't go back to default when I restart the app. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the email and username using toolbar view object.

```
Toolbar toolbar = ((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
```

Now get the view of textviews of toolbar, and set text.

```
TextView txt_email = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.txt_email);
TextView txt_username = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
txt_email.setText("abc@stackoverflow.com");
txt_username.setText("Username");
```